# What changed the next responder of my NSWindow?

Tags: cocoa, nswindow, chain, nsresponder

I'm trying to debug an issue caused by the change of a next responder of the main `NSWindow`. I have an internal `NSView` and a chain of custom `NSResponder`, however even after debugging and sticking breakpoints all over every `setNextResponder`, I never stop on one of them and all I do is just changing the window's style.

How can I get what changed the next responder? Is it just because of the style change? I can't find it in the documentation. Is there something I'm missing? What are the operations that can mess up with the responders chain?

Comment: You can actually answer your own question to help future visitors, it would be more visible than a comment. Consider also linking the documentation and quoting the relevant parts.

Answer (score 3):

Using watchpoints I found out exactly that `[super setStyleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask];` was setting to nil the `_nextResponder` of the `NSWindow` instance. In the official documentation I found out that [**Some style mask changes cause the view hierarchy to be rebuilt**](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWindow/setStyleMask:). I hope might be useful to someone else...